# recursive 'ls' giving absolute filenames

Tags: shell, ls, recursive

When I do 'ls -R' in a directory, I get something like

```
./dir1
dir2 file1.txt file2.txt

./dir1/dir2
file3.txt file4.txt
```

but I would like a command that gives me

```
./dir1/file1.txt
./dir1/file2.txt
./dir1/dir2/file3.txt
./dir1/dir2/file4.txt
```

such that I can use it in a for-loop to process all files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`find(1)`.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)  This will do exactly what you want.  You can also specify various filter conditions such as file type (don't include directories), newer than the time stamp on a given file etc.  The man page will describe these in more detail.

Also, take a look at the `-exec` option; you may be able to use this instead of iterating over the output.

Comment: @thias Also have a look at `find -ls` option.

Comment: @thias I'll amend Concerned's suggestion to a strong recommendation: use `find … -exec`. Do not use `for x in $(find …)`: it does not work, because it can't cope with file names containing whitespace. `find -exec` is exactly the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bash ≥4 or zsh or ksh93 ≥o+<sup>1</sup>, you can make the shell do recursive globbing: the `**/` wildcard matches directories at any depth. In bash, you need to enable the feature with `shopt -s globstar` (bash), and beware that up to bash 4.2, `**/` traverses symbolic links to directories. In ksh93, you need `set -o globstar` (ksh93); in zsh, it's always enabled.

```
for x in **/*.txt; do …
```

If you need your script to be portable to other shells, [use the `find` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21754/recursive-ls-giving-absolute-filenames/21755#21755), it's exactly the right tool for the job. Note that `find` is an external command that can work in two ways: it can generate a list of files, and it can execute commands for each file. If you want to execute a command for each file, use `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec chmod a+r {} +
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Among non-Bourne shells, `fish` and `tcsh` also have the feature</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`tree` is also a nice tool for this.

I use

```
tree -Dpushfag --du
```

you can also add a limit in depth, for example maximum 2 levels:

```
tree -Dpushfag --du -L 2
```

Comment: very nice tool but it does not really solve the problem posed in the question (at least not with the arguments you provide)