# Why doesn't my loop over the output of ls work?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ls

I am trying to feed Directory names into a for loop.  My code is as follows:

```
td='/Test/TopDir/'
cd "$td" 
for x in $(ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d'/'); do
  echo x=$x
done
```

The top directory I run this on looks like this when running an ls command:

```
ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    4 Jason    users         4096 May  6 06:36 2014-02-02 - Jebby (
drwxrwxrwx    3 Jason    users         4096 May  6 06:09 2014-02-04 - Jebby (
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 May  6 06:09 @eaDir
-rw-r--r--    1 Jason    users      3956225 Jan 26 10:17 DSC01062.JPG
-rw-r--r--    1 Jason    users      3927603 Jan 26 10:18 DSC01063.JPG
```

The results of my for loop is as follows:

```
x=2014-02-02
x=-
x=Jebby
x=(
x=2014-02-04
x=-
x=Jebby
x=(
x=@eaDir
```

As you can see the for loop is breaking the directory names into sub-pieces after each space.  In this example I only want the For Loop to execute three time with the three directories:

1. 2014-02-02 - Jebby (
2. 2014-02-04 - Jebby (
3. @eaDir

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alternative to get the above output: `ls -d */ | xargs -I{} echo 'x='{}`

Comment: [Don't parse ls!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Very true, @Floris. Guess you're no sheep, huh?

Comment: @mikeserv - I am not sure what your comment means but I am going to assume it is a compliment?

Comment: @Floris - yes, it is a compliment.

Comment: Related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21754/recursive-ls-giving-absolute-filenames

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Avoid parsing the output (or at least the filename portion) of `ls` in shell scripts if at all possible.**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) It will always give issues with word-splitting where filenames contain whitespace.

If you want to iterate over directories you can do that using a simple shell glob i.e.

```
for d in */; do 
  echo "$d"
done
```

The `ls` command should only be used for displaying directory listings in human-readable form in the terminal.

Comment: You should also explain how to check if a file is a directory.

Comment: It's a directory just by virtue of matching the `*/` glob, I think?

Comment: @Kevin `*/` only matches directories (and symlinks to directories).

Comment: This is bad advice. It will have issues as long as you don't handle them. They can be handled. And besides, `set -- */` is more useful than `for ... in ...`

Comment: @mikeserv what issues? How would you use `set -- */` here?

Comment: @terdon - just like that. And i meant `ls` - you can use it. It bothers me when people rule out a tool completely because somebody blogs about how it was inconvenient to use in a certain scenario. It just feels a little... sheepy.

Comment: @mikeserv in this particular case, all problems go away if you don't use `ls`. The whole point here is that there are spaces in the file names and avoiding it is a good habit to get into. Anyway, seriously, I'd be interested to see what you mean with `set -- */`. I don't really know what it does and have no idea how it could be useful here. Why not post an answer with it?

Comment: @terdon I dont want to post an answer is why not. And `set -- */` will set your positional parameter array to all directories in the current directory - so you now have a shell array of the data you wish to work with. So `$#` becomes a count of all of the folders and all of the rest of those useful array features. As for `ls` - spaces are as easily handled as changing `$IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

Using @mikserv's [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128788/why-doesnt-my-loop-over-the-output-of-ls-work/128793?noredirect=1#comment206582_128793), you can do

```
cd /Test/TopDir/
set -- "$PWD" */
cd /somewhere/else
td=$1 ; shift 
for x; do
  echo x="${td}/$x"
done
```

Comment: No. You dont need `for ... in ...` if its already in your `$@`array you can just do `for ...` - personally i like `while ${1+:} false ; do` though.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks, edited. I made this CW, so feel even freer than usual to add any other improvements. I just thought it was a good idea and should be here.

Comment: Whats a CW - what does that mean?

Comment: @mikeserv [Community wiki](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), also see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). In short it's used to make posts into collaborative efforts that the community edits. An often useful side effect is that the author gets no rep from it.

Comment: There - maybe its a little clearer now why i said it was more useful. I guess you suckered me into doing the answer after all.

Comment: @mikeserv heh, I knew you'd fall into the trap :). Thanks!