# How to make a for loop to read directory names with spaces in them?

Tags: ls, for, touch

I need to create a script to scan folders in a directory and take the name of each folder, make a .txt file, name it with the name of the folder and put inside that folder.

For example:
A directory that has 3 folders in it named "1" "2" and "3"
I want to create a .txt file in each folder named with the name of that folder
so that folder 1 has "1.txt" in it
folder 2 has "2.txt" in it
etc..

I managed to do that with this script:

`for i in $(ls -d */);  do  touch  "$i $(basename $i).txt" ;  done`

The problem is I want to do the same thing but with folders that has spaces in their names.
For example:
If I have a folder named "Test Me"
It will give an error saying something like this:

`Me: no directory with that name`

It will see only the word "Me" and treat it as a folder and not "Test Me" as a whole.

How can I do that ?

**Update**
This is the solution, it is commented below by TAAPSogeking (Thanks again to him)
`for dir in *;  do  [ -d "$dir" ] && touch "$dir/$dir.txt";  done`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128788/why-doesnt-my-loop-over-the-output-of-ls-work

Comment: `ls` is only causing problems. In this case you should simply use `*`, so `for i in */; do ...`

Comment: Thanks man, it gave me this error though as the folder name is "Test Me (5656)"
`basename: extra operand ‘(5656)’

Comment: let shell replace basename also:`for dir in */; do touch $dir${dir%/}.txt; done` (@sudodus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the immediately directories and not all nested sub directories.
The following assumes you are currently in the same directories and the directories you want to loop over

```
for dir in *; do 
    [ -d "$dir" ] && touch -- "$dir/$dir.txt"
done
```

1. This will loop over every file in the current directory
2. filter for
   directories (including symlinks to directories).
3. And then create the requested file in the specified
   directory

Also you may be interested in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which point out common errors/bad practices (like the use of ls in this case)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I really can't. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need the additional check for directories - use `*/` instead and the glob will expand to only include directories

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
touch -- *(/e['REPLY+=/$REPLY.txt'])
```

Where the `/` glob qualifier restricts the glob expansion to files of type *directory* (change to `-/` if you also want to consider symlinks to directories), and the `e` qualifier `e`valuates the given code to modify the path (stored in `$REPLY`). Add the `D` (for `D`ot files) qualifier to also do it for hidden directories (`.` and `..` not included in any case).